# Final Cuto Pro X sort by modified date

Tags: final-cut-pro-x

I have few videos in one event. The problem is, that for some reason (probably because of moving them from disk to disk), **`Modify date` is the original one (the correct one)** rather than `Create date`.

In the finder, I can do: `sort by` -> `Modified date`, and everything is correctly in order. But when I import those videos into the event in the FCP, it keeps sorting by `Content Created`.

I cannot see an option in FCP that would allow me to sort videos in the event by "modification date", is it even possible ? (or at least keep the order imposed by the finder?)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the question is asked on other places as well, with no answer so I will propose a workaround as I don't think FCP X gives you option to sort by `Modified` metadata field.

Bash script that adds a modification date at the beginning if each file in the directory in epoch. Then sorting in FCP by name.

1. Open `terminal` and go the the directory you want to apply changes (in my case a directory with videos).
2. do `cat > script.sh`
3. Enter: `for f in *; do mv -- "$f" "$(stat -f %m "$f")-$f"; done`
4. Hit `enter` and then `ctrl + D`
5. Now type: `bash script.sh`
6. Open FCP X and do `Sort by: name`

**Note:**
In order to revert the process, all you have to do is to replace what is in the point `3` to: `for f in *; do mv -v "$f" "${f#*-}"; done`